# QuickFIX/J: Enable protocols and ciphersuite setting

Tags: java, quickfixj

I was looking at the [this link](http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/usermanual/1.5.0/usage/configuration.html#Socket) for help regarding QuickFIX/J configuration.

How would I enable TLS 1.2 as the enabled protocol? Is it:

```
[SESSION]
EnabledProtocols=Tls1.2
```

What if I wanted to specify ciphersuites? For example, to only use ciphersuites `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384` and `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384`. Is it:

```
[SESSION]
CipherSuites=TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
```

Can you put commas?

There is no example of how to specify this in documenation.

Answer (score 3):

The basic configuration elements to specify TLS 1.2:

```
SocketUseSSL=Y
EnabledProtocols=TLSv1.2
```

To specify a Java Keystore along with those settings:

```
SocketUseSSL=Y
SocketKeyStore=certificate.jks
SocketKeyStorePassword=<password to keystore>
EnabledProtocols=TLSv1.2
```

Where `SocketKeyStore` points to the Java Keystore file on disk. Note that only Java Keystores are possible in QuickFIX/J up to and including version 1.6.2.

From version 1.6.3 onwards, it is possible to specify other types of key stores (e.g. PKCS12) using the `KeyStoreType` configuration element. For e.g. PKCS12, the configuration would look like:

```
SocketUseSSL=Y
SocketKeyStore=abcdef.pfx
SocketKeyStorePassword=<password to keystore>
KeyStoreType=PKCS12
EnabledProtocols=TLSv1.2
```

In QuickFIX/J 1.6.3 onwards, you can use the `CipherSuites` configuration element to specify cipher suites enabled for use with the SSL engine. For example, in configuration:

```
CipherSuites=TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Please refer to the [1.6.3 configuration manual](https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/1.6.3/usage/configuration.html#Miscellaneous) for more details.

Comment: Thank you. Do you by any chance know of a good way to verify it is using TLSv1.2 for example?

Comment: Documentation for current version (2.3.0) has no mentions of KeyStoreType-s other than JKS, so I assume they dropped support for PKCS12 at some point.

Comment: @AlexanderGonchiy I am seeing in [2.3.0 configuration documentation](https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/usage/configuration.html) the KeyStoreType element still present though. It lists the default value being `JKS` (that is the value if element KeyStoreType is ommitted). I would be surprised if other key store types would be dropped.

Comment: The "Valid Values" field for the KeyStoreType element is empty, which I read as only "JKS" being supported. Considering otherwise, where would one look for a list of all accepted keystore types? (Google finds no occurrences of "PKCS" in the docs which makes me think it's something external to QuickFIX/J )

Comment: @AlexanderGonchiy You can see [here](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/895224da1a05055bc99d936920d1e1ed7edc9935/quickfixj-core/src/main/java/quickfix/mina/ssl/SSLContextFactory.java) that a KeyStore is created from `java.security.KeyStore` using the `KeyStoreType`. You would expect the supported types in Java to be supported in QuickFIX/J, and PKCS seems like a very typical key store type. You can see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html) for instance that every Java implementation requires support for at least PKCS12.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close to the correct setting. For properly enabling TLS 1.2, you should configure it as of below:

```
[SESSION]
EnabledProtocols=TLSv1.2
```